# R removing selected characters from a string

Tags: r, database, data-cleaning

Sorry in case of duplication, but the solutions I have seen does not solve my issue.

I have a data frame (df). One of its variables (df$Year) includes a list of years, such as:

```
 > df$Year

 Year
 2001–                       
 2013–                     
 2016–                      
 2003–                      
 2012–2013                      
 2013–                      
 1993–2007, 2010–
```

In case of multiple years, I just want to keep the last one (i.e. rather than '1993–2007, 2010–' only '2010') and get rid of the '-'.
Yet, I have tried with:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(df$Year, "[[:digit:]]4$"))
```

but this does not seem to work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` for a one liner:

```
df$Year <- sub(".*(\\d{4})\\–?", "\\1", df$Year)
df$Year

[1] "2001" "2013" "2016" "2003" "2013" "2013" "2010"
```

### Demo

Note that the dashes you use in your year ranges appear to be em dashes (or maybe en dashes), not the regular ASCII character.

Comment: Thank! This works deleting the multiple years. 
I have combined your with the solution of Andre Elrico above and the whole thing is solved, hence thanks again to both of you.
I still don' get what was wrong in my solution, though...